# MATLAB: 10 fold cross Validation without using existing functions

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, cross-validation

I have a matrix (I guess in MatLab you call it a struct) or data structure:

```
  data: [150x4 double]
labels: [150x1 double]
```

here is out my matrix.data looks like assume I do load my file with the name of matrix:

```
5.1000    3.5000    1.4000    0.2000
4.9000    3.0000    1.4000    0.2000
4.7000    3.2000    1.3000    0.2000
4.6000    3.1000    1.5000    0.2000
5.0000    3.6000    1.4000    0.2000
5.4000    3.9000    1.7000    0.4000
4.6000    3.4000    1.4000    0.3000
5.0000    3.4000    1.5000    0.2000
4.4000    2.9000    1.4000    0.2000
4.9000    3.1000    1.5000    0.1000
5.4000    3.7000    1.5000    0.2000
4.8000    3.4000    1.6000    0.2000
4.8000    3.0000    1.4000    0.1000
4.3000    3.0000    1.1000    0.1000
5.8000    4.0000    1.2000    0.2000
5.7000    4.4000    1.5000    0.4000
5.4000    3.9000    1.3000    0.4000
5.1000    3.5000    1.4000    0.3000
5.7000    3.8000    1.7000    0.3000
5.1000    3.8000    1.5000    0.3000
```

And here is my matrix.labels look like

```
 1
 1
 1
 1
 1
 1
 1
 1
 1
 1
 1
 1
 1
 1
 1
 1
 1
 1
 1
```

I am trying to create 10 cross fold validation without using any of the existing functions in MatLab and due to my very limited MatLab knowledge I am having trouble going forward with from what I have. Any help would be great.

This is what I have so far, and I am sure this probably not the matlab way, but I am very new to matlab.

```
function[output] = fisher(dataFile, number_of_folds)
    data = load(dataFile);
    %create random permutation indx
    idx = randperm(150);
    output = data.data(idx(1:15),:);
end
```

Comment: try this http://www.mathworks.com/help/bioinfo/ref/crossvalind.html

Comment: then use those generated indices on your matrix

Comment: I am sorry I want to do it without using crossvalind function

Comment: oh sorry! did not read the question properly. hmm one sec.

Comment: :) not a problem, if you are writing a solution any comments would be great since i am trying to learn matlab.

Comment: aight give it a look and let me know if you catch any bugs/ have questions

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is my take for this cross validation. I create dummy data using magic(10) also I create labels randomly. Idea is following , we get our data and labels and combine them with random column. Consider following dummy code.

```
>> data = magic(4)

data =

    16     2     3    13
     5    11    10     8
     9     7     6    12
     4    14    15     1

>> dataRowNumber = size(data,1)

dataRowNumber =

     4

>> randomColumn = rand(dataRowNumber,1)

randomColumn =

    0.8147
    0.9058
    0.1270
    0.9134


>> X = [ randomColumn data]

X =

    0.8147   16.0000    2.0000    3.0000   13.0000
    0.9058    5.0000   11.0000   10.0000    8.0000
    0.1270    9.0000    7.0000    6.0000   12.0000
    0.9134    4.0000   14.0000   15.0000    1.0000
```

If we sort X according column 1, we sort our data randomly. This will give us cross validation randomness. Then next thing is to divide X according to cross validation percentage. Accomplishing this for one case easy enough. Lets consider %75 percent is train case and %25 percent is test case. Our size here is 4, then 3/4 = %75 and 1/4 is %25.

```
testDataset = X(1,:)
trainDataset = X(2:4,:)
```

But accomplishing this a bit harder for N cross folds. Since we need to make this N times. For loop is necessary for this. For 5 cross folds. I get ,  in first f

1. 1st fold : 1 2 for test, 3:10 for train
2. 2nd fold : 3 4 for test, 1 2 5:10 for train
3. 3rd fold : 5 6 for test, 1:4 7:10 for train
4. 4th fold : 7 8 for test, 1:6 9:10 for train
5. 5th fold : 9 10 for test, 1:8 for train

Following code is an example for this process:

```
data = magic(10);
dataRowNumber = size(data,1);
labels= rand(dataRowNumber,1) > 0.5;
randomColumn = rand(dataRowNumber,1);

X = [ randomColumn data labels];


SortedData = sort(X,1);

crossValidationFolds = 5;
numberOfRowsPerFold = dataRowNumber / crossValidationFolds;

crossValidationTrainData = [];
crossValidationTestData = [];
for startOfRow = 1:numberOfRowsPerFold:dataRowNumber
    testRows = startOfRow:startOfRow+numberOfRowsPerFold-1;
    if (startOfRow == 1)
        trainRows = [max(testRows)+1:dataRowNumber];
        else
        trainRows = [1:startOfRow-1 max(testRows)+1:dataRowNumber];
    end
    crossValidationTrainData = [crossValidationTrainData ; SortedData(trainRows ,:)];
    crossValidationTestData = [crossValidationTestData ;SortedData(testRows ,:)];

end
```

Comment: So if I have the data file can I pass that into X..?

Comment: also how can i use random permutation to pick the fold..?

Comment: This works great but I manage to put this in a function function [training_data, test_data] = diagFisher(dataFile, x) and then at the end assigned     training_data = crossValidationTrainData;
    test_data = crossValidationTestData; but how do i access these ?

Comment: can you explain the code inside the for loop i am trying to understand, i got it to work, but I am not really clear things mainly since i am new to matlab.

Comment: @Null-Hypothesis I added more explanation. Please look and add comment if anything is unclear.

Comment: Thanks in my case rows have meaning such as first four columns are data and last column is the label so I decided to drop the randomness and in the loop after if and else I trains rows and test rows to 10 X 2 cell and return the 10 folds where the matrix looks like [Training Test]. But thanks for great description and for the code

Comment: this fails if we try to a data set with 178 X 13 any thougths..?

Comment: Could you give me an example where it fails?

Comment: I used some parts of the code, works great for me (+1). However,it's not stratified cross validation, so may not include all classes in training or test set.

Answer (score 3):

Hahaha sorry, no solution. Don't have MATLAB on me right now so can't check code for errors. But here's the general idea:

1. Generate k (in your case 10) subsamples

   1. Start two counters at 1 and preallocate new matrix: `index = 1; subsample = 1; newmat = zeros("150","6")` < 150 is the number of samples, 6 = 4 wide data + 1 wide labels + 1 we will use later
   2. While you still have data: `while ( length(labels) > 0 )`
   3. Generate a random number within the amount of data left: `randNum = randi(length(labels))`? I think that's a random int that goes from 1 to the size of your labels array (it could be 0, please check the doc - if it is, do simple math to make it 1 < rand < length)
   4. Add that row to a new data set with labels: `newmat(index,:) = [data(randNum,:) labels(randNum) subsample]` < that last column is the subsample number from 1-10
   5. Delete the row from data and labels: `data(randNum,:) = []; same for labels` < note this will physically remove a row from the matrices, which is why we have to use a while loop and check for length > 0 rather than a for loop and simple indices
   6. Increment counters: `index = index + 1; subsample = subsample + 1;`
   7. if subsample = 11, make it 1 again.

At the end of this, you should have a large data matrix that looks almost exactly like your original, but has randomly assigned "fold labels".

1. Loop over all this and your executing code k (10) times.

EDIT: code placed in more accessible manner. NOTE it's still pseudo-y code and is not complete! Also, you should note that this is NOT AT ALL the most efficient way, but shouldn't be too bad if you can't use matlab functions.

```
for k = 1:10

index = 1; subsample = 1; newmat = zeros("150","6");
while ( length(labels) > 0 )
    randNum = randi(length(labels));
    newmat(index,:) = [data(randNum,:) labels(randNum) subsample];
    data(randNum,:) = []; same for labels
    index = index + 1; subsample = subsample + 1;
    if ( subsample == 11 )
        subsample = 1;
    end
end

% newmat is complete, now run code here using the sampled data 
%(ie pick a random number from 1:10 and use that as your validation fold. the rest for training

end
```

---

EDIT FOR ANSWER #2:

Ok another way, is to create a vector that is as long as your data set

```
foldLabels = zeros("150",1);
```

Then, looping for that long (150), assign labels to random indices!

```
foldL = 1;
numAssigned = 0;
while ( numAssigned < 150 )
    idx = randi(150);
    % no need to reassign a given label, so check if is still 0
    if ( foldLabels(idx) == 0 )
        foldLabels(idx) = foldL;
        numAssigned++; % not matlab code, just got lazy. you get it
        foldL++;
        if ( foldL > 10 )
            foldL = 1;
        end
    end
end
```

---

EDIT FOR ANSWER #2.5

```
foldLabels = zeros("150",1);
for i = 1:150
    notChosenLabels = [notChosenLabels i];
end
foldL = 1;
numAssigned = 0;
while ( length(notChosenLabels) > 0 )
    labIdx = randi(length(notChosenLabels));
    idx = notChosenLabels(labIdx);
    foldLabels(idx) = foldL;
    numAssigned++; % not matlab code, just got lazy. you get it
    foldL++;
    if ( foldL > 10 )
        foldL = 1;
    end
    notChosenLabels(labIdx) = [];
end
```

---

EDIT FOR RANDPERM

generate the indices with randperm

```
idxs = randperm(150);
```

now just assign

```
foldLabels = zeros(150,1);
for i = 1:150
    foldLabels(idxs(i)) = sampleLabel;
    sampleLabel = sampleLabel + 1;
    if ( sampleLabel > 10 )
       sampleLabel = 1;
    end
end
```

Comment: still working on this but posting midway so people can point out errors/you can start asking questions

Comment: I am bit confuse with the newmat = zeros("150","6"); what is 6 here..?

Comment: Ah ok, so i should make that more clear. Basically, just for convenience, we are mashing together your two arrays. One is 4 elements wide, and the other just 1, right? that is 5 columns. We also reserve 1 for the label we are giving that sample later. Is that clear?

Comment: I see then I assue that extra label column is to identify which fold..? did i get it right..?

Comment: THanks, so I can use a function where I pass in the data file and 10 as folds right..? aslo can you explain this line, i am not sure, data(randNum,:) = []; same for labels, here you say same for the labels but I am really getting it, sorry i am super new to matlab

Comment: ok well I just posted a simpler solution, but that line in Answer #1 just deletes that row from the vector. the vector is physically shortened by 1 with that element gone (think of it as MATLAB's NULL)

Comment: Brilliant let me give this one a try.

Comment: @Null-Hypothesis Please note that the performance of #2 COULD be worse than #1 due to the random index finding. Therefore, a better way would be to generate another vector with indices you haven't already chosen and delete ones you have from that.

Comment: I see thanks alot, I do have another question, so in my question I posted how i started i used randperm function to generate idx can i use that here..?

Comment: yes you can! most certainly! it eliminates much of the boiler-plate code around this. but i thought you couldn't use matlab functions? or is randperm ok?

Comment: if you can use randperm, that last bit at the end of my answer is all you need to generate a vector of fold # labels for your data

Comment: One tiny thing, I do have more 1,2,3 has labels i only put first few rows of the 150 X 1 vector

Comment: any chance you can wrap a final version in a function?