# How to perform 10 fold crossvalidation using matlab?

Tags: matlab, cross-validation

I am trying to perform a 10-fold cross validation (CV) on Linear regression models to determine the CV_mean square error. My data consists of 500 items in a <500x1> double in matlab.

Comment: Welcome to SO. We are not here to write your code. Please add a [mcve] detailing the code you have tried. Explain why it does not work for you and what the expected results are.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the statistics toolbox you can use `cvpartition`.

If you have access to the bioinformatics toolbox you can use `crossvalind`.

If you do not have access to any toolboxes, you are going to have to write your own function. There seems to be a SO entry on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12630293/matlab-10-fold-cross-validation-without-using-existing-functions?rq=1).

**Edit**

What I linked to seems to be pretty long-winded. I doubt this is efficient, but you could write a function like this:

```
function [TrainInd, TestInd] = KFold(k, NoFolds, length)

    start = floor((k-1)*length/NoFolds)+1;
    stop = floor(k*length/NoFolds);
    TestInd = false(1,length);
    TestInd(start:stop) = true;
    TrainInd = ~TestInd;

end
```

And then call it like this:

```
for k = 1:10
   [TrainInd, TestInd] = KFold(k,10,11);
   TrainData = x(TrainInd);
   TestData = x(TestInd);
end
```